# Shell Script to convert hexadecimal values in a file to decimal

Tags: bash, shell, syntax-error, bc

I have a file named as `text` containing all hexadecimal numbers. I wrote the following code to convert those values to decimal:

```
for line in `cat text`; do

arp=$(echo "ibase=16; $line" | bc);echo $arp
     done
```

But it's giving me the following error:

```
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
```

My input file contains one column of hexadecimal values, e.g.

```
428a2f98 
71374491 
b5c0fbcf
```

Answer (score 3):

If your hex numbers are in the following form:

```
0x1
0x2
0x3
0x4
0x5
0x6
0x7
0x8
0x9
0xA
0xB
0xC
0xD
0xE
0xF
```

I mean prefixed with `0x` you can use:

```
while read line
do
     printf '%d\n' $line

done < text
```

Ouput:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
```

Comment: No Ashkan, Its not prefixed with 0x. And I cant change the contents in my text.

Comment: Modifying the third line like this works for me `printf '%d\n' "0x"${line}`

Answer (score 3):

It's not `bash` that produces the error, it's `bc` which requires hexadecimal numbers to use uppercase letters while your input file uses lowercase letters.

If you use `bash 4` you can use `${foo^^}` to expand `$foo` to uppercase:

```
bc <<< "ibase=16; ${line^^}"
```

or you can use `tr`:

```
bc <<< "ibase=16; $(tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' <<< "${line}")"
```

Comment: Adrian, how can I write the from a file named as text, containing all hexadecimal numbers. Want to convert all the hexa numbers from text.txt to binary numbers.

Comment: @user3514650 In what format are your numbers? You can edit your question and add an excerpt of your input file.

Comment: @user3514650 I updated my answer, this should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is answered, when you don't know exactly the position of numbers, this sed oneliner can help other people looking for help, and only finding this question on the net:

```
$ cat file | sed 's/^/echo "/;s/(0x\(..\))/(\$(echo "ibase=16;\U\1\E"\|bc))/g;s/$/"/e'
```

#### Explaining:

- `s/^/echo "/` adds `echo "` at start
- `s/(0x\(..\))/(\$(echo "ibase=16;\U\1\E"\|bc))/g` needs further explaining:

  1. find `(0x..)` pattern. You can change to `^........` in your case
  2. creates a subshell `$()` where hex pattern `\1` is procesed by [bc](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bc)

     - `\U` is used to uppercase hex digits. `\E` stops uppercasing.
- `s/$/"/e` adds `"` at end and process line with sh

You can test it on [xmodmap](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xmodmap) output, which output hexadecimal characters for modifiers, while [xev](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xev) shows modifiers as decimals.

Hope it becomes handy in other use cases

Comment: I was looking for exact this solution, was completely missing the significance of first and third sed commands there. Thanks a lot!!
Just one thing, in the search pattern, `..` can be replaced by `[0-9a-fA-F]*` for converting any hex number to decimal

Answer (score 0):

```
while read line
do
    arp=$(echo "ibase=16; $line" | bc)
    echo $arp
done < in.txt
```

For `in.txt`

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
A
B
C
D
E
F
A0
A1
FF
```

This prints:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
160
161
255
```

Comment: Lutz, I am getting again the same error as mentioned earlier.

Comment: @user3514650, are you working in bash and get the error?

Comment: @BMW as you told I changed the code to :                       while loop < text
do
    echo $loop
    arp=$(echo "ibase=16; $loop" | bc)
    echo $arp
done     But its giving error as "hex_binary: line 1: loop: command not found"

Comment: @user3514650 I've change my answer the way BMW recommended.

Comment: @LutzHorn Getting the same error even with your changed code. I think the error is comming because of bc.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on [albfan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28012546/19181126) and posted for the same reason (other people looking for help, and only finding this question on the net).
I am expanding on it to allow for replacements in files that contain backslashes, backticks, double quotes and dollar signs.
This way it is also much safer to use on unknown inputs, preventing code injection.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
cat $1 | sed -r 's/\\/\\\\/g;s/`/\\`/g;s/"/\\"/g;s/\$/\\$/g;s/0x([0-9A-Fa-f]+)/\$(echo "ibase=16;\U\1\E" \| bc)/g;s/^/echo "/;s/$/"/e'
```

To answer the original question, the 0x needs to be removed:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
cat $1 | sed -r 's/\\/\\\\/g;s/`/\\`/g;s/"/\\"/g;s/\$/\\$/g;s/([0-9A-Fa-f]+)/\$(echo "ibase=16;\U\1\E" \| bc)/g;s/^/echo "/;s/$/"/e'
```

###### Simple demonstration:

Input line:

```
console.log("This is a number: 0xffffff")
```

Intermediate form:

```sh
echo "console.log(\"This is a number: $(echo "ibase=16;FFFFFF" | bc)\")"
```

Output line:

```
console.log("This is a number: 16777215")
```

###### Usage:

Save as hex-to-decimal.sh, `chmod 555 hex-to-decimal.sh` to make it executable and uneditable and run with `./hex-to-decimal.sh inputfilename > outputfilename`

Or just run as a one-liner with `` cat inputfilename | sed -r 's/\\/\\\\/g;s/`/\\`/g;s/"/\\"/g;s/\$/\\$/g;s/0x([0-9A-Fa-f]+)/\$(echo "ibase=16;\U\1\E" \| bc)/g;s/^/echo "/;s/$/"/e' > outputfilename ``

##### Explanation:

`cat $1`

- List the contents of the input file line by line.

`| sed -r`

- Apply a bunch of transformations (in this case substitutions and one execution) to each line of text and print the result to stdout.

`s/\\/\\\\/g;`

- Place a backslash before every backslash in this line.

`` s/`/\\`/g; ``
`s/"/\\"/g;`
`s/\$/\\$/g;`

- Do the same for backticks, double quotes and dollar signs.

`s/0x([0-9A-Fa-f]+)`

- Substitute anything that starts with `0x` and is followed by a hexadecimal number.
- For the original question version, `0x` is omitted and it matches anything that is a valid hexadecimal number. For example causing `fridge` to be replaced with `15ri13g14`.

`/\$(echo "ibase=16;\U\1\E" \| bc)/g;`

- Replace it with `$(echo "ibase=16;` + the first group capitalized (the number without `0x`) + `" | bc)`
- `\$(echo "ibase=16;\U\1\E" \| bc)`

  - `$(<command>)`

    - starts a child bash instance that executes the command and resumes execution with it being replaced by the output of the child (has no effect from within single quote (`''`) strings)
  - `\U\1\E`

    - `\U` makes what comes after uppercase, `\1` is the first group (which was `[0-9A-Fa-f]+`), `\E` makes the uppercasing not apply to what comes after it. In other words; the hexadecimal number, made uppercase.
  - `echo "ibase=16;<hexadecimal number>" | bc`

    - Convert a hexadecimal number (input base = 16) to decimal (default output type) with the `bc` command.

`s/^/echo "/;`

- Place `echo "` at the start of the line.

`s/$/"/e`

- Place `"` at the end of the line and execute the line.

Answer (score 0):

Using the bc command for converting hexadecimal values to decimal is an option, but not an essential one. Additionally, bc may seem needlessly complex. In fact, Bash offers simpler alternatives such as the `$((...))` syntax or `$(printf "%d" "...")` that can produce the same result.

#### Using `$((...))`:

```bash
$ cat file | sed -Ee 's@^@echo "@' \
  -e 's_\b0x[0-9A-Fa-f]+_\$((&))_g' \
  -e 's/$/"/e'
```

#### Using `$(printf "%d" "...")`:

```bash
$ cat file | sed -Ee 's@^@echo "@' \
  -e 's_\b0x[0-9A-Fa-f]+_\$(printf "%d" &)_g' \
  -e 's/$/"/e'
```

### Explantion:

`-E` flag

- Used for extended regular expressions.

`-e` flag

- Used for adding scripts to sed command.
- It's same as using `;` which is used to add multiple sed scripts.
- Using `e` flag makes it easier to read, so why not?

`s@^@echo "@`

- `^` represents the beginning of each line.
- It matches start of a line and inserts `echo "`.

`s_\b0x[0-9A-Fa-f]+_\$((&))_g` &&

`s_\b0x[0-9A-Fa-f]+_\$(printf "%d" &)_g`

- `\b` is used for word boundary, so it only matches hex values

  What the heck does that even mean?

  So, I had JavaScript and Python scripts that included variables and functions containing hexadecimal values, such as the variable `_0x371ac6`. Using `\b` ensures that we're only substituting hex values.
- `0x[0-9A-Fa-f]+` is for matching hex values.
- `\$((&))` is used to replace the matched hex value with `$((hexVal))`.
- `\$(printf "%d" &)` is used to replace the matched hex value with `$(printf "%d" hexVal)`.

  `&` is the whole match or the 0th group of the match.

  `\0` can be used instead of `&`.

`s/$/"/e`

- `$` represents the ending of each line.
- It matches end of a line and inserts `"`.

  `/e` is used to run each line as a `sh` command.